# How to call this function with reflection method，Parameters are delegates and generics

Tags: c#, reflection

```
// this is code
    public class Foo1Parent
    {
    }
    public delegate void CallBack<T>(T arg1);
    public delegate void CallBack(); 
    public class Foo
    {
    public void openWindow<T>(CallBack<T> onWindowAwake) where T:Foo1Parent
     {
      Debug.Log("test");
      onWindowAwake(T);
     }
//I use reflection to call methods "openWindow"
 public void openCWindow(CallBack onback, string dialogName)
    {
        Type t = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(dialogName);
        MethodInfo meth1 = this.GetType().GetMethod("openWindow");
       object[] obj = new object[] { null }
        meth.Invoke(this, obj );
    }
```

}
     //

> Blockquote

The parameters of a generic is CallBack onWindowAwake I don't know how to do it

Comment: This is not C code. Please [edit] your question and use correct language tag.

Comment: This is not a Java code as well. @flyhighandlong, You would be get faster response if the tags are correct. Please try to figure out the programming language and re-tag the question.

Comment: @Prashant You are correct, looks more like c#, corrected

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are trying to do, or why.  You aren't doing anything with the `t` variable or the `onback` parameter.  What is the expected value of `dialogName`?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: The parameters of a generic is CallBack<T>  onWindowAwake I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what the question here is but, from the looks of things you are asking:

`How do I invoke the generic method openWindow using reflection?`

If this is the question then what you need to do after you get the `MethodInfo` which has the  generic definition of  `openWindow` is to create a generic method using [MakeGenericMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netframework-4.8)

Example:

```
MethodInfo genericDefinition = this.GetType().GetMethod("openWindow");

MethodInfo genericMethod = genericDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Foo1Parent));

object[] obj = new object[] { null };

genericMethod.Invoke(this, obj);
```

This is the only way you can invoke a generic method, it is not possible to invoke a definition because, it doesn't know what `T` is.

Comment: Thanks, this is a generic reflection call，This generic T is created in openWindow, you mean you can't do this, I use another method to do it, no generics, thank you very much, you can write Chinese, it's amazing.